# login to website for scraping with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to get links to genetic pathways from a website. First I need to login but am having trouble. I have very little experience with scraping so any pointers or general 'how to' information about this will be very much appreciated along with an exact answer.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/genesets.jsp?collection=CP:BIOCARTA'
session1 = requests.Session()
params = {'login':'my_email'}
session2 = session1.post(URL, data=params)

pathways_links = []

for link in soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'wrapper'}).find(
    'div', attrs={'id':'contentwrapper'}).find(
        'div', attrs={'id':'content_navs'}).find(
            'table', attrs={'id':'geneSetTable'}).find('a')['href']:
    pathways_links.append(link)
    print link
```

unfortunately it doesn't seem to log me in. I get:

```
'div', attrs={'id':'content_navs'}).find(
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

if I ask it to print links before the 'content_navs' div then I get:

```
<div id="content_full">
<h1>Login to GSEA/MSigDB</h1>
<h2>Login</h2>
<a href="register.jsp"></a>Click here</div>
```

Any solutions would be much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first login at `http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/login.jsp` and then go to the other location.

The first step, is to create a session object; which will persist cookies and other session details. Next, you need to login and then finally pass the contents to BeautifulSoup:

```
s = requests.Session()
data = {'j_username': 'you@email.com'}
s.post('http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/login.jsp', data=data)
r = s.get('http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/genesets.jsp?collection=CP:BIOCARTA')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

# the rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but session.Session() is throwing an error:     s = session.Session()
NameError: global name 'session' is not defined